# Regex an integer value (Like 3 or 24)

Tags: regex

In some code I used `3` instead of `Image_Channel_Count`, so now I have to refactor it all. I only want to find all occurrences of the integer `3`, and not `-3`, `3.0`, `03`, or etc.

I tried `\b3\b` in regex but it would select values like `0.3`, which I didn't want.

How can I do this in regex?

Comment: a regex can only operate on text rules.. so you need to have very accurate criteria to match the full space of occurrences.. `(?<![0.-])(3)(?!\.)` would match `3` not preceeded by `.` , `-`, `0` and neither followed by `.` for example. But maybe it's not enough

Comment: What about matching it with just preceding space like ` 3 ` or depending on the language  ` 3 | 3;|=3;|, 3` Like Diego mentioned above here, you need to think in all cases